# JSON Parsing Error "NoneType object is not callable"?

Tags: python, json

**Code:**

```
                body = '%s' % message.get_body()
                logging.error(body)
                parsed_body = json.loads(body)
```

**Body contains:**

> [{u'content': u'Test\r\n', u'body_section': 1, u'charset': u'utf-8', u'type': u'text/plain'}, {u'content': u'Test\r\n', u'body_section': 2, u'charset': u'utf-8', u'type': u'text/html'}]

**Error:**

```
line 67, in get
    parsed_body = json.loads(body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 38, in errmsg
    lineno, colno = linecol(doc, pos)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: Im thinking body might be None?

Comment: does `get_body` already return a string?

Comment: Yeah it does. I was just trying random stuff trying to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`body` is a string (you get it with '%s' % ...), so it **shouldn't** contain Python string-encoding such as `u'content'`.

This means that either get_body() returns a complex object, and `'%s' % ...` is converting it into a python-output string which **is not** JSON, or something is already "fixing" the string when get_body returns it. The error is then elsewhere.

Example:

```
import json

# This is a correct JSON blob

body = '[{"content": "Test\\r\\n", "body_section": 1, "charset": "utf-8", "type": "text/plain"}, {"content": "Test\\r\\n", "body_section": 2
, "charset": "utf-8", "type": "text/html"}]'

# And this is a correct object
data = json.loads(body)

# If I were to print this object into a string, I would get 
# [{u'content': u'Test\r\n', u'type': u'text/plain', u'charset'...
# and a subsequent json.load would fail.

# Remove the comment to check whether the error is the same (it is not on
# my system, but I'm betting it depends on JSON implementation and/or python version)

# body = '%s' % data

print body

print json.loads(body)
```

Comment: You're right. I feel foolish now. It was already parsed into a list with a dict in it. How do I tell the difference when I log something between json and an object that's being printed as a string? The u'stuff' a good telltale?

Comment: Well, I've been bitten by this particular bug so many times I don't bleed anymore. Yes, I usually check for the u'. And yes, I too feel foolish. Every time :-(

Comment: @Joren I often `print(type(obj))` to make sure.